# ASP .NET ViewModel error

Tags: include, viewmodel

I have a problem . When he calls AssortmentController thus "/ assortment/kindslist?kindname=horror"
I get the error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Isf.Models.Movie]', but this
>   dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'Isf.ViewModels.HomeViewModel'.

This is my AssortmentController:

```
public class AssortmentController : Controller
    {
        AssortmentRelationships db = new AssortmentRelationships();
        // GET: Assortment
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult ExplicationMovie(string moviename)
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult KindsList(string kindname)
        {
            var kinds = db.Kinds.Include("Movies").Where(k => k.KindName.ToUpper() == kindname.ToUpper()).Single();
            var movies = kinds.Movies.ToList(); 
            return View(movies);
        }

        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult KindsMenu()
        {
            var kinds = db.Kinds.ToList();

            return PartialView("_KindsMenu", kinds);
        }
    }
```

KindsList view:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" id="right-list">
             @Html.Action("KindsMenu")
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10">
             test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

_KindsMenu view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Isf.Models.Kind>

<ul>
    @foreach (var kind in Model)
    {
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">aaa</button>
            </a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

_MoviesList view:

```
@model Isf.Models.Movie

<div class="remove-all-margin-padding" id="category_view">
     <img class="hover_detail" src="~/img/covers/1.jpg" />
 </div>
```

PartialView is ok. All is ok if I comment KindsList action... 
I dont use viewmodel because I use html.action in KindsList view...
I've done so many times and it was always ok